# Treeview control defined in user control

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I have create a User Control named "ControlTree.vb" in which place "Treeview" duly named "TreeControl" and Want to access the tree control on form button click and populate the tree. Tree is populated according to button requirement but now needs to executre double_click event on selected tree node.

Treeview populated on button click. I can not place the treeview control on form itself, so I create a user control and place the tree view in that control. 
So please guide how to execute the double click event on treeview node.

thanks

Comment: What do you want to happen after this double click? Add new nodes? Show a messagebox?

Comment: On double click, open new form

Answer (score 0):

So, you said you want to execute a double click event. This could mean that you want to perform a double click OR that you could do some action in the double click event.

If you want to perform an action within that event, you just need to fill the handler for it. For example:

```
  Sub treeView1_NodeMouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, _
  ByVal e As TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs) _
Handles treeView1.NodeMouseDoubleClick

Try 
    'do whatever action you want 
Catch
    MessageBox("Error!")
End Try
```

End Sub

I copied this code from the MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.nodemousedoubleclick(v=vs.110).aspx

Now if you want to call this function, then you need to do a perform action.

These are very basic event focused options. I would suggest that you look up some basic tutorials on how to do VB.NET with forms.

**EDIT:** If you want to open a form on the double click event, after the try line just add a formName.show().

Comment: I am able to do any action on treeview if treeview control place on particular form but i want to access the treeview from user control to form

Comment: So, you want to double click a node, and show a new form?